# Where to find jni_md.h on CentOS OpenJDK 1.8

Tags: java, maven, centos, java-native-interface

I am building a java project using JNI and built using native-maven-plugin.

I am able to successfully compile and run my code on my local MacOS environment. However, this will need to run on a CentOS environment too and so I need to compile a .so library along my .jnilib .

I was thinking of copying jni_md.h from the CentOS environment to my local machine and provide the path to that header file to a CentOS compiler on my local machine.

However, I cannot find jni_md.h on the CentOS environment. I installed OpenJDK 1.8 using yum but I did not get an include/ folder in it.

- Where can I find a linux version of jni_md.h to use on my local machine?
- Bonus question: would my plan even work and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In my experience using cross compilers is not worth the hassle. Easier to run a CentOS VM on your local machine. And you can install everything you need there (maybe you installed only the OpenJDK JRE on the other machine, this would not include the headers)

Answer (score 0):

This file should be located here

```
$JDK_HOME/include/linux
```

Question is, why do you need this one? You can't compile code that is supposed to run at CentOS at macOS - this will not work. And `*.h` files have nothing to do here. They are just headers.

Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

You can find there a sample project that will compile just fine, at macOS and Linux.

All you have to do is to make sure to set `JAVA_HOME` such way it points to your JDK installation.

Have fun with JNI!